# What will be the word order in converting this to reported speech?

Tags: word-order, indirect-speech

We need to convert the following to reported speech:

> Why have you taken a room on the tenth floor?

I am confused about the word order.

Should it be

> He asked her why she had taken a room on the tenth floor.

or

> He asked her why had she taken a room on the tenth floor.

or neither? Why?

I suppose since we convert an interrogative sentence into a declarative one (on conversion to reported speech), the correct one would be the first. However, the it doesn't 'sound' right. And English is not lacking in exceptions.

Comment: @tchrist, there was a related question about this word order a short time ago (which I answered).  "the word order" moves to the end by a rule akin to Ross's Heavy NP Shift.  The problem lies in your grammar, not in his.

Comment: @GregLee You’re right. I don’t know what I was thinking.